# Test if a local TCP port is free

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, tcp

I need to test if a TCP port is free. I wrote this method:

```
private bool freePort(int port) {
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    IAsyncResult result = socket.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Loopback, port, null, null);
    bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, true);
    try{
        socket.Close();
    }catch(Exception){}
    return !success;
}
```

This works in Windows 7 but not in Windows XP.

In winXP sometimes works and sometimes gives false answer...

Comment: If nobody else has a good idea, you can check if you can open a socket to that port. It can give different results depending on the adress you use to refer to yourself.

Comment: What happens the other 80% of the time? This is very wrong code, if you find out it is free then you have no guarantee whatsoever that it is still free a nanosecond later, another process could open the port.  Same kind of logic behind Windows not having a function to check if a file is locked.

Comment: Ok, it can not be 100% sure but I need just a check before running an apache process. If something are already running and listening on tcp 80 I can get it and stop the process. The problem is WHY in XP sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work.

Comment: @HansPassant: It can be useful to check beforehand if you want to avoid a floods of exceptions when debugging.

Comment: For first, is that code correct to open a TCP port in asynchronous mode?

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect to _"In winXP sometimes works and sometimes gives false answer..."_? There is no _"fake TCP port in use"_ API call in Windows XP, if you were wondering. **You** will have to analyze what exactly is going wrong. Do you mean the connection succeeds while actually no process is listening, or does it not connect while there is (timeout)?

Comment: My question is why AsyncWaitHandle of Socket object returns "false" if there are no app listening on that port?

Comment: Because of a slow firewall that makes the connection last more than a second?

Comment: It is probably better to exactly attempt what Apache will attempt: open the port.

Comment: @CodeCaster if that can I will get a false positive, not a false negative... do you agree?

Comment: @usr this can be a good alternative, let me try...

Comment: @usr this is perfect! please answer me. With  new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port).Start(); I could test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably better to exactly attempt what Apache will attempt: open the port, instead of connecting to it.

```
using (var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, port))
    listener.Start();
```